# Rails: Cannot match webhook signature in json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, webhooks

I need to be able to verify the signature of a webhook but I cannot seem to match the value correctly.  The tool I'm using provides the expected signature as a URL param with the request:

```
YOUR_CALLBACK_URL?signature=ofdiwefjojiefwojowefoi
# www.websitename.com?signature=ofdiwefjojiefwojowefoi
```

They state that the way they generate the signature is:

> The signature is generated using an HMAC-SHA-256 base64 digest of the raw HTTP Body of the Webhook post using this Webhook secret.
>
> You can generate the signature in php as follows:
>
> ```
> $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
> $s = hash_hmac('sha256', $request_body, 'mySecret', true);
> echo base64_encode($s);
> ```

In my app, I attempt to generate a matching signature by doing the following:

```
key = ENV['ESIGNGENIE_SECRET']
data = params.to_json
signature = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, data)).strip()
return signature == params["signature"]
```

This seems to always be wrong.  Am I doing something wrong here?  I can't tell if I'm encountering issues due to the way Rails parses the json object or what.

Comment: Have you tried printing both signatures out to compare and see how rails is parsing it?

Comment: yes, I have and they are different.

Comment: Even stranger, I used Hookbin to capture the webhook initially and when I use the body that is displayed in hookbin and convert it to a string and do the exact same digest, I get the correct signature back.  I don't understand the difference

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I realized that my mistake was trying to use `params` to generate the signature when I should have used `request.body.read`.  It should look like the following:

```
key = ENV['ESIGNGENIE_SECRET']
data = request.body.read
signature = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, data)).strip()
return signature == params["signature"]
```